# Combining multiple Types into a byte array

Tags: c#, .net

What is the most efficient way to combine multiple variables of different Types into a single byte-array?

Take the following example data:

```
short a = 500;
byte b = 10;
byte[] c = new byte[4];
```

How could I combine these three variables into one byte array without wasting to much time and memory?

Think of it like this (Pseudocode):

```
var combinedArray = new byte[] { a, b, c };
```

I thought of different ways, including unsafe code, converting them to `byte[]` using `BitConverter` and using Linq's Concat.

I need an array in the end, not just an `IEnumerable`, because I need to send this data via udp.

Are there any methods I did not think of?

Comment: The BitVector32 .net helper  in System.Collections.Specialized can sometimes be useful in these situations.

Comment: Use serializers like Json.Net, XmlSerializer, BinaryFormatter etc.... That way you can handle more complex cases you may need in the future..

Comment: @Eser Json.Net or XmlSerializer are no options to me, because they generate a lot of bloat and are essentially text, but BinaryFormatter looks promising!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the BinaryWriter combined with a MemoryStream.

```
var buffer = new MemoryStream();   
var writer = new BinaryWriter(buffer);

writer.Write(a);
writer.Write(b);
writer.Write(c);

writer.Close();    
byte[] bytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

But do note that there is no padding or alignment. The array `c` will start at an odd offset.

You will also have to verify the Big Endian / Little Endian contract with your client.

Comment: If this is sending over udp, i would consider specifying a length of the array at the start and a check sum, however i'm probably being overly pedantic

Comment: @TheGeneral - that doesn't depend on the medium, it would entirely depend on the format(s) agreed by sender & receiver. Not specified here. When the array size is fixed and known, you wouldn't add a Length.

Comment: Agreed in full, Just putting it out there as although udp is fairly reliable on a local network, there is no guarantee of every packet arriving and ordering. anyway i upvoted

Comment: This seems to be a nice solution to me. Will the padding and alignment be an issue, when I am the one sending and recieving the packages? The data sent via udp is in a format that is known to the other side of the connection. If it is an issue, how could I fix it?

Comment: When you read with a BinaryReader then there is no issue. But when you control both sides, JSon and XML are alternatives to consider.

Comment: I would read with a BinaryReader of course. Json and XML generate to much bloat for my purpose, especially XML. But thank you, I accept your answer!